# Deploying container images to OpenShift

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, redhat

I want to apply this article ([Getting any Docker image running in your own OpenShift cluster](https://blog.openshift.com/getting-any-docker-image-running-in-your-own-openshift-cluster/)) for an image from the [RedHat Registry](https://registry.redhat.io). I chose the [rhel8/redis-5 image](https://access.redhat.com/containers/?tab=images&get-method=registry-tokens#/registry.access.redhat.com/rhel8/redis-5). I am not clear about the steps to be followed.

I tried `oc new-app --docker-image=registry.redhat.io/rhel8/redis-5`. This did not work even after copying the Docker configuration details from the RedHat Registry Service account. Is `oc new-app` expected to work with images stored outside of Docker Hub?

Next, I tried the OpenShift secret option.

Following the details from [Registry Service account](https://access.redhat.com/RegistryAuthentication) to use OpenShift secret, we have to run this command. `kubectl create -f chainhead-secret.yml --namespace=NAMESPACEHERE`. Is this what is called as the image pull secret? Is there a `oc` command equivalent?

The next step is to update Kubernetes configuration with a `yaml` snippet as shown below. Where  should it be consumed - `oc`, web console, `kube-whatever` command, etc?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: somepod
  namespace: all
  spec:
    containers:
      - name: web
        image: registry.redhat.io/REPONAME

    imagePullSecrets:
      - name: some-pull-secret
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with OpenShift, however I find some things that might be helpful for you.

Besides of what @Arockiasmy K mentioned in previous answer, the YAML syntax is incorrect. It won't create a pod: `spec` must be on the same lever as `kind`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: somepod
  namespace: all
spec:
  containers:
  - name: web
    image: <image>
```

`$ kubectl apply -f <pod-yaml>`

Another thing, make sure that you already have `namespace` called "**all**" and remember that secret must be in the same `namespaces` as `Pod`.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Ok, I will use `kubectl apply`. The YAML syntax is from RedHat Container catalog for the `rhel8/redis-5` image - https://access.redhat.com/containers/?tab=images#/registry.access.redhat.com/rhel8/redis-5

Answer (score -1):

You can create the secret using `kubectl` as well as `oc`. Both works in Openshift.

`oc create -f redhat-secret.yml --namespace=NAMESPACEHERE`

Ensure that the hostname is registry.redhat.io. You have two ways to attach it to deployment.

- You can mention this secret into the pod,dc configuration as imagePullSecrets.
- You can add this secret as imagePullSecrets into default SA (in the project). `oc edit sa default`.

Comment: ```apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: {POD-NAME}
  namespace: {TARGET-NAMESPACE or all}
  spec:
    containers:
      - name: web
        image: registry.redhat.io/rhel8/redis-5

    imagePullSecrets:
      - name: {PULL-SECRET-NAME}
```
I hope you received this template from Redhat registry to deploy Redis 5 app. You will need to store it in YAML file and execute `oc create -f redis5.yml`

Comment: Where should the `yaml` be pasted or passed as a file name to a command?

Comment: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/cli_reference/differences_oc_kubectl.html This link will help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200306/discussion-between-arockiasmy-k-and-cogitoergosum).